# (Ionic / Angular) Swiper.js Autoplay is not running

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, swiper.js, ionic6

**—— Issue ——**

Hello, I dont understand why swiper is not starting like autoplay must be.

When I look into the swiper instance from `(swiper)` event, I got this results :

1. swiper.params.autoplay: `{delay: 1000, enabled: true}`
2. swiper.autoplay: `{ running: false, paused: false, pause: [Function], run: [Function], start: [Function], stop: [Function] }`

It seem swiper as load my configuration correctly but wont start the autoplay.

Hope someone can understand why and help this thread .

**—— Code ——**

*I added `SwiperModule` in imports of my `NgModule` (home.module.ts).*

**home.page.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import Swiper, { Autoplay } from 'swiper';
import { IonicSlides } from '@ionic/angular';

SwiperCore.use([ Autoplay, IonicSlides ]);

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.page.html',
  styleUrls: [ './home.page.scss' ]
})
export class HomePage implements OnInit {

  swiperConfig = {
    slidesPerView: 1,
    spaceBetween: 0,
    autoplay: {
      delay: 1000
    }
  }

  constructor() {}
  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

**home.page.html**

```html
<ion-content [fullscreen]="true">
  <swiper direction="horizontal" [config]="swiperConfig">
    <ng-template swiperSlide>Slide 1</ng-template>
    <ng-template swiperSlide>Slide 2</ng-template>
    <ng-template swiperSlide>Slide 3</ng-template>
    <ng-template swiperSlide>Slide 4</ng-template>
  </swiper>
</ion-content>
```

**home.page.scss** is empty

Comment: No way, same problem here. I was to return to old way (deprecated) till this error fixed.

Old way -> Using ionic components <ion-slides> and <ion-slide>

Comment: Adrien Villalonga, did you find a solution to this issue?

Comment: No (I didn't try the old way like @JuanmaFont) and may post this issue on the ionic/capacitor forum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For my Ionic 6 / Angular project, I needed to obtain a reference to the Swiper and then set the "running" property to true for it to actually start moving.

I.e. in your component HTML:

```
<swiper ... other properties ... #swiperComponent>
```

In your page.ts obtain the reference to that component:

```
@ViewChild('swiperComponent') swiperComponent: SwiperComponent;
```

And then:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
   this.swiperComponent.swiperRef.autoplay.running = true;
}
```

Bit of a hack but it fixed it for me.

Comment: This should be marked as the right answer

Comment: I guess something still wrong, and ionic should update the documentation or fix it

Comment: This answer is suitable for Ionic React as well. I used autoplay.start();

Answer (score 3):

### **UPDATE AS OF JANUARY 2024** `angular v14`, `ionic v6`, `swiper v11`

None of the above solutions worked for me at all and then what ended working was to declare `autoplay` not as a binding variable but as a regular attribute of `swiper-container`

An example of my code below:

```
<!-- Swiper Lower Ads -->
<div style="position: relative" *ngIf="this.flags.editSite.settings.showAds">
  <swiper-container
    style="margin-bottom: 40px"
    [loop]="true"
    [pagination]="true"
    [navigation]="true"
    autoplay="true">
    <swiper-slide *ngFor="let ad of flags.editSite.settings.lowerAdvertisementList; let i = index">
      <a [href]="ad.ad_link" target="_blank">
      <img [src]="ad.target" /></a>
      <div class="ad-badge">AD</div>
    </swiper-slide>   
  </swiper-container>
</div>
```

You can read more via this article here: [Setting Up Swiper Slides w/ Ionic & Angular](https://medium.com/@imtiazraqib/angular-w-ionic-swiper-slides-autoplay-not-working-issue-fix-bc9521160af6)

Comment: Great one, but where is the css style for AD?

Comment: @fanbondi you mean for the AD badge or my entire swiper-slide to re-create the screenshot you see in the Medium article?

Comment: Yes exactly! I am sure I can give it a go if you don't have the CSS.

Comment: @fanbondi here you go `.ad-badge {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  border-radius: 0px 30px 0px 30px;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #f4f5f8;
}`

Comment: Searched for hours, and then the solution was so simple, thank you very much!

Comment: This worked for me for Angular v17, Swiper v11 and no Ionic

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to solve it would be just to set autoplay.running to true, on swiper event, like this:

```
<swiper #swiper [config]="config" (swiper)="swiper.swiperRef.autoplay.running = true">
```

Answer (score 1):

No way, same problem here. I was to return to old way (deprecated) till this error fixed. Old way -> Using old ionic components  and

The old way ->

```
Component.ts

import SwiperCore, { Autoplay, Keyboard, Pagination } from 'swiper';
import { IonicSlides } from '@ionic/angular';
SwiperCore.use([Autoplay, Keyboard, Pagination,  IonicSlides]);
```

and into template component.html ->

```
    <ion-content id="presentation">
    
        <ion-slides [options]="{ autoplay:true} (ionSlideReachEnd)="onReachEnd()">
    
            <ion-slide *ngFor="let item of data" swiperSlide>
            </ion-slide>
        </ion-slides>
     </ion-content>
```

NOTE: Now, Mar/2023 to use old way you must install old swiper v8 (do not install default v9)

```
npm install swiper@^8
```

Answer (score 0):

This work me

```
<swiper-container [loop]="true" [speed]="1000" [autoplay]="{enable:true,delay:7000}" >
      <swiper-slide>
        <img src="../../../assets/img/qs.jpg" alt="">
      </swiper-slide>
      <swiper-slide><img src="../../../assets/img/App-Maintenance-cost.png" alt=""></swiper-slide>
      <swiper-slide><img src="../../../assets/img/steamuserimages-a.akamaihd.jpeg" alt=""></swiper-slide>
    </swiper-container>
```